# XML not valid because of null values while XSD has nillable="true" and minOccurs="0"

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a problem with my XSD. I have set two xs:elements with `nillable="true"`and `minOccurs="0"` because when i extract their values they are `'' (null)` but the xsd validator says '' is not a correct value for this elements .

I use `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">` as ns, tried the `xsi:nil="true"` but it says i can't use it in schema elements.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits of your schema and xml instance files please?

Comment: <xs:element name="date_fin_reel" type="xs:date" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>  <xs:element name="numero_convention"  type="numero_convention" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/> , the value of those elements in the XML generated are null (''), i still get the error indicated in the answer

Comment: Please edit your question and provide minimal but complete samples of the schema and the input that does not validate. Which parser/validator do you use?

Comment: Its ok, the problem solved by replacing the ns to xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance. Thank you anyways!